# Unable to navigate to index action in my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, new to Rails. Trying to create an ecommerce app from scratch. Defined an `Order` model to track my orders and `OrderItem` model to track each of my order in my cart. i want to add a **button** to my Order page that lets me add more items to my cart. In the `show.html.erb` for Order, I am writing the following

```
code:
<%= button_to "Add to Cart", products_path %>
```

This link takes me to the create action of the **Products** model, instead of the **index** action. I tried to change the path to `root_path` which lists all the products in my Product model, but again the link takes me to the POST request instead of GET, showing me error. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Check your `routes.rb` file to have the route specific to the get request of products model as

```
get "/products" => "products#index"
```

alternatively if you have products model in your app then add

```
resource: products
```

This will automatically adds route to your **index** action

or else you can try this:

```
<%= button_to "Add to Cart", root_path, method: :get %>
```

Comment: i have already defined my routes as resources: products. Hence, i am expecting that products_path automatically takes me to product#index. Alas! it takes me to products#create. No ideas why...

Comment: @RahulPoddar add your routes.rb file

Comment: Merchant::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :orders

  resources :order_items

  resources :products

  root 'products#index'

  match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: :get

  match "/login" => redirect("/auth/twitter"), as: :login, via: :get
  match "/logout" => "sessions#destroy", as: :logout, via: :get
end

Comment: @RahulPoddar Once try by specifying `<%= button_to "Add to Cart", root_path, method: :get %>`

Comment: @RahulPoddar Happy to hear that it worked, i will update my answer if it worked for you you can accept my answer. and this is my email_id: anusha.m547@gmail.com